# Why this build error?

Tags: c++, gcc, windows-8.1

I try to build hydra on Win 8.1 with cygwin but I get this build error when running make:

```
   -DHAVE_MATH_H
hydra-pop3.o:hydra-pop3.c:(.text+0x697): undefined reference to `MD5_Init'
hydra-pop3.o:hydra-pop3.c:(.text+0x697): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `MD5_Init'
hydra-pop3.o:hydra-pop3.c:(.text+0x6f2): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
hydra-pop3.o:hydra-pop3.c:(.text+0x6f2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `MD5_Update'
hydra-pop3.o:hydra-pop3.c:(.text+0x70d): undefined reference to `MD5_Update'
hydra-pop3.o:hydra-pop3.c:(.text+0x70d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `MD5_Update'
hydra-pop3.o:hydra-pop3.c:(.text+0x71e): undefined reference to `MD5_Final'
hydra-pop3.o:hydra-pop3.c:(.text+0x71e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `MD5_Final'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: hydra-pop3.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'hydra' failed
make: *** [hydra] Error 1
```

What can be done? I could run ./configure without error, but then it failed running make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check LIB_PATH, you need to include lib file exported "MD5_Init" function.